# "secure" versus "in securing" tense issue

Tags: tenses

Okay this one bothers me for some reason.

> "We assisted four municipalities secure funding for public work projects."

or

> "We assisted four municipalities in securing funding for public work projects..."

I know it's a tense issue and the bottom one is grammatically correct, but struggle because the top version "sounds" better to me and the second version sounds busy.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a preposition like "in" or "with", followed by a gerund, you should use the verb "help" rather than "assist". The following is grammatical and sounds better:

> We helped four municipalities secure funding for public work projects.

Even though "assist" and "help" are synonyms, they don't function the same way in sentences. "Assist" requires the prepositional phrase, it's optional after "help".